# Variable out of scope when applying event listener

Tags: javascript

Why is `i` out of scope in the `callback function` in this code?

```
// All menu items collection
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');

// Loop trough all menu items and attach
// event listeners.
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        // Check if element truely exsists
        if (menuItems[i]) {
            menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                ////////////////////////////////
                // NOTE: i, is out of scope! //
                //////////////////////////////
                var icon = menuItems[i].children[1],
                    submenu = menuItems[i].children[2];

                // Change icon color
                if (icon.style.background !== "blue") {
                    icon.style.background = "blue";
                } else {
                    icon.style.background = "red";         
                }

                // Show/hide submenu
                if (submenu.style.display !== "block") {
                    submenu.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    submenu.style.display = "none";         
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: It isn't defined when the event is triggered only when the event listener is set?

Comment: Is that an question of an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `i` is not out of scope. It's just that the event handler will be called some time after the loop has completed, so the variable `i` has a value that points outside the `menuItems` array.

Wrap the code in a function, to create a scope where you have a copy of the variable for each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  // Check if element truely exsists
  if (menuItems[i]) {

    (function(i){  

      menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var icon = menuItems[i].children[1],
            submenu = menuItems[i].children[2];

        // Change icon color
        if (icon.style.background !== "blue") {
          icon.style.background = "blue";
        } else {
          icon.style.background = "red";         
        }

        // Show/hide submenu
        if (submenu.style.display !== "block") {
          submenu.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          submenu.style.display = "none";         
        }
      });

    })(i);

  }
}
```

As the event handler uses the `i` variable, it will be captured in a closure object for that function. Each event handler will have a separate closure object, but without the function wrapper to create a separate `i` variable for each iteration, all the closures would capture the same variable.

The closure for a function contains all local variables that the function uses from the outer scope. Unless `menuItems` is a global variable, it will also be in the closure.

Comment: Javascript isn't my strong point but could you get the menuitem from the event args as the target of the event?  Wouldn't that eliminate the need to retain i?

Comment: Great explanation, I have a request though. Could you add to your answer representation on how Javascript will store those two `EventListeners` diffrently as an `object`. I would love to see how Javascript stores the `i` variable but I would like to see it as an `object` it would help me a whole much!

Comment: @Jesse: Yes, as the variable `i` is only used to get the element that was clicked, in this case it would also work to get the target of the event.

Comment: @Johnny: I added some more about how closures work. I hope that answers your question.