# Setting events on Google Maps dynamically doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using my database to get different positions that will be set on a Google Map as markers. I'm using JavaScript to also set event listeners for all these dynamically loaded markers, but I have a problem with this one:

```
var markerCollection = [];

//pushing data into the array...

for ( var j = 0; j < markerCollection.length; j++) {
    console.log(j + ' ' + markerCollection[j].shopId);
    $.proxy(google.maps.event.addListener(markerCollection[j].gmapMarker, "click", function(e) {
        console.log(markerCollection[j].shopId);
    }),this);
}
```

The code tells me `markerCollection[j]` is undefined. Yet if I type a hardcoded way (markerCollection[0]) it will work. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: if $.proxy is an async function, when it executes that it will loose value of j, its not in the scope

Comment: @juvian, not using proxy gives the same error.

Comment: does it give error in the console log or in the addListener?

Comment: The error is triggered for the console.log inside the addListener() method. The one above it, although it's the same thing, does not give me an error.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense, though it was in the addListener. You are making an event listener, so it won't retain value of j, when click is made the for has already finished

Comment: This should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203992/variable-out-of-scope-when-applying-event-listener

Comment: @juvian ok that worked. I don't really get it but it works. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, don't know much about theory so sorry I couldn't explain well, but glad you got it to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the answer linked in one of comments is more complicated than it needs to be. There is a simpler way to do this that is easier to understand:

```
var markerCollection = [];

        //pushing data into the array...

for ( var j = 0; j < markerCollection.length; j++) {
    addMarker( markerCollection[j] );
}

function addMarker( marker ) {
    console.log( marker.shopId );
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker.gmapMarker, "click", function(e) {
        console.log( marker.shopId );
    });
}
```

That's really all you need. Each time the `addMarker()` function is called, that invocation of the function has its own `marker` variable which refers to one of the elements in the `markerCollection` array. And that `marker` variable remains valid when the listener callback gets called later in response to a click.

It's doing the same thing as the more complicated version, but in a way that I think is much easier to follow. Note how the code in `addMarker` uses the `marker` variable instead of having to say `markerCollection[i]` every time.

Also, you don't need the `$.proxy()` bit unless you need to pass a `this` value along, which you're not using here. So leave it out if you don't need it. Simpler is better!