# How to pass the index to addeventlistener in for? JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i have a little problem with passing the index to eventlistener in for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    console.log("XD");
    todos[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        trashShow[i].style.display = "inline";
    });
}
```

Communicate shows up that say "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". I think that the index is just wrong so there is not this element in the array. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable out of scope when applying event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203992/variable-out-of-scope-when-applying-event-listener)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587714/addeventlistener-for-index-how-to-use-closure

Answer (score 3):

> i have a little problem with passing the index to eventlistener in for
>   loop.

If you declare the iterator variable `i` with `let`, rather that with `var`, you will see that the loop increments `i` correctly each time within the event listener and never returns an `undefined` error.

**Working Example:**

```js
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

var section1Divs = sections[0].getElementsByTagName('div');
var section2Divs = sections[1].getElementsByTagName('div');

for (let i = 0; i < section1Divs.length; i++) {

    section1Divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        section2Divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    });

    section1Divs[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        section2Divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(191, 191, 191)';
    });
}
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 12px;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>

<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: Thanks. I needed the same help and changed var to let and it worked. I wish the author of this question would vote correct as he was doing the same thing I was doing. Although I was using click, not mouseover.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanJ.Pecany - when I first started learning javascript (in 2013) it was still ES5 and `let` & `const` didn't exist. Applying `eventListeners` to multiple nodes in a loop was one of the first really difficult things I had to learn. When `let` arrived it made things much easier!